# Google map api on huawei

Tags: android, google-maps, mapkit, huawei-mobile-services

Is it possible to use google map api, and firebase on huawei ? I found alternative - map kit. But is it possible to use google map ? When I launched my application on the Huawei map was not displayed, on other brands, the map is displayed correctly. Does this mean that for Huawei devices I need to use a separate api for working with maps?

Comment: Xda's article https://xda-developers.com/here-wego-maps-and-navigation-huawei-appgallery-available/ says Here map now available on Huawei's app store, maybe Here map would work on Huawei devices. Here map documentation can be found here https://developer.here.com/products/here-sdk.

Comment: I have multiple applications that use Google Maps API and run perfectly on Huawei devices. Does the map appear on devices of other brands? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use Google Maps on Huawei devices that do not have Google Mobile Services.
You can integrate the Huawei Map Kit instead.
please refer this https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-mapkit

Also there is really useful SDK to implement Huawei Map Kit and Google Map services. This SDK allows you to implement both services in to one app. If google play services available on the phone google map will be rendered, if huawei mobile services available on the phone huawei map will be rendered

https://github.com/iDroidDev/MapKit

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what about the firebase and push notifications

Comment: You need to implement huawei push kit to the your app. Please check this link for Push Kit. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit. Which service of firebase? My suggestion is to replace all firebase services with huawei services.

Comment: FCM. Would you recommend replacing completely Google Maps Api with some other? Or is it better to support both Google Maps Api and MapKit

Comment: It is up to you. You can use product flavor, change your package name and replace google dependencies with huawei or you can implement both services to the your app. If you replace dependencies you will have 2 versions of app and you will publish one of them to the AppGallery and the other one to the Google PlayStore. If you support both services, you can publish same app to the both store.

Comment: @Android Maybe you want to take a look at this https://github.com/m0skit0/maps-wrapper