# Here Android SDK compatibility with Huawei

Tags: android, google-maps, huawei-mobile-services, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I am creating an app that currently integrates Google Maps SDK, the thing is we have some users with Huawei, which cannot render Google Maps because of the lack of Google Play Services. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661571/google-map-api-on-huawei) that mentions what I just said.

I wanted to know if [Here Maps SDK](https://developer.here.com/products/here-sdk) has considered users with Huawei phones. If so, is there an extra step to follow in this regard?

Comment: Here Maps does not use Google Play Services for their maps so you can use them

Answer (score 0):

You are advised to use Huawei [Map Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-MapKit/).

According  to the [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-brief-introduction-0000001061991343#section1261123620147), the following are Map kit support Devices:

[image]

If you want to use the map service in your app, and also want your app to run on both Huawei phones and Google Android phones, you can integrate both GMS Map Kit and HMS Map Kit. Then your app will use HMS Map Kit on Huawei phones, while using GMS Map Kit on Google Android phones.

You can use this IDE plug-in called [HMS Core Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/) to help you analyze where GMS is used in your code. HMS Core Toolkit supports analysis of manual conversion, aiming to increase the conversion efficiency. It provides two conversion policies: Add HMS API and To HMS API. You can choose one as required.

For more details about conversion, [this question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59974428/have-both-gms-and-hms-in-the-project).